# How long you can stay out of France while you have 10 year permanent resident card?

Tags: france, residency

I am out of France for consecutive 6 months, wanted to know how long I can stay before I lose my permanent resident status. I still need few months to finish my matters abroad before I can return. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Warning : I am not a lawyer.

The [following article](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=0F3402C0523D60CB2902DB05D43E9151.tplgfr25s_3?idArticle=LEGIARTI000032171517&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20180908) from the *Code de l'entrée et du séjour des étrangers et du droit d'asile* mentions that after three consecutive years of residence out of France the *carte de résident* is expired. This period can be prolonged if the holder request it.

> Article L314-7
>
> ```
> Modifié par LOI n°2016-274 du 7 mars 2016 - art. 20
> ```
>
> La carte de résident d'un étranger qui a quitté le territoire français
>   et a résidé à l'étranger pendant une période de plus de trois ans
>   consécutifs est périmée, de même que la carte de résident portant la
>   mention " résident de longue durée-UE " accordée par la France lorsque
>   son titulaire a résidé en dehors du territoire des Etats membres de
>   l'Union européenne pendant une période de plus de trois ans
>   consécutifs.
>
> La période mentionnée ci-dessus peut être prolongée si l'intéressé en
>   a fait la demande soit avant son départ de France, soit pendant son
>   séjour à l'étranger.
>
> En outre, est périmée la carte de résident portant la mention "
>   résident de longue durée-UE " accordée par la France lorsque son
>   titulaire a, depuis sa délivrance, acquis ce statut dans un autre Etat
>   membre de l'Union européenne, ou lorsqu'il a résidé en dehors du
>   territoire national pendant une période de six ans consécutifs.